# Why does every program have to have an account?

Tags: user-accounts, visual-studio

I've just installed new MS VS, even it asked me for enter.
AutoCAD and Word has an account.
Is it the secret plan to watch me? )))
Why since not a long time it is not enough to use a OS user account to keep all data safe?

Comment: The new world wants all your data on-line and/or they want you to check-in occasionally for licencing reasons. Regardless, as-is this question will only attract opinion-based answers, as there is no real, single answer for your question. Voting to close as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licensing. They're probably doing license validation server-side to prevent binary tampering. I know for a fact Visual Studio and AutoCAD does. Not sure about Word.

Don't be offended, but you're probably not all that interesting for them to watch anyway.